# How to host RESTfull API on main domain and end developers consume it via another domain, so that they will not come to know the original domain

Tags: web-services, rest, networking

Here is the situation:
We want to host REST APIs on main domain server (lets say **maindomain.com**) and willing to expose these APIs via another domain server (say **beta.com**), so that end developers/API consumers should not come to know the **maindomain.com**.

I'm not aware what are the possible ways to achieve this.

Let me know the ideas/technologies, that will be enough. (just wanting hints..)

Comment: You don't host anything on domain _names_. You host on servers, to which you then point domain names. In your case, both names could point to the same server. What's is the question here, exactly?

Comment: And there's no such thing as "domain server" (not in your case, anyway). Correct terminology is important.

Comment: What is exactly I'm looking here is to: host few REST APIs developed in .net Framework environment and expose to other developers. While consuming API Url should be different. (It should not show original API Url,instead display another url/domain..)

Comment: yeah, so? What's the problem with just pointing a second domain to your app?

Comment: How to enable the second Url which in-turn calls main API?